# Unable to find the wrapper “https” - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to install symfony 3 in my computer. I open the command prompt in windows 10 system and i write the following command

```
php -r "readfile('https://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

in return I get this warning

> Unable to find the wrapper “https” - did you forget to enable it when
>   you configured PHP?
>
> php warning readfile(https://symfony.com/installer): failed to pen stream: invalid argument in command line code on line 1

so how to enable it ?

Comment: Is php_openssl.dll enabled?

Comment: when I search php_openssl.dll in php.ini I d'ont found it

Comment: Look for `extension=php_openssl.*` if it has a `#` in column one remove it.

Comment: Remember to check that there are not 2 `php.ini` files. You dont say what OS etc you are using

Comment: @RiggsFolly i found extension=php_openssl.dll whitout ;

Comment: Then check also for another `php.ini` in `c:\php\php.ini` maybe. The CLI uses a different `php.ini` to Apache sometimes

Comment: From command line do `php --ini` and it shoudl tell you where the CLI is getting its `php.ini` file from

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes it work for me, then i write these commands `cd projets` ` move symfony c:\projects ` and ` php symfony ` here it's ok. But whene i want to create the symfony application  with `symfony new application_name` this error appears  `symfony 
is not recognized as a command`

Comment: and this error to curl error 60 see http //curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

Comment: Also check `extension php_curl.dll`  is enabled

Comment: @Riggs  Yes is enabled without ;

Comment: I was trying to uncomment *extension=php_openssl.* in C:/xampp/php/php.ini but it was not the right file in may case. I have a file *php.ini* in *C:/tools/php* which I guess is the global configuration of php. Uncommenting *extension=php_openssl* from this file did the trick for me. I am using xampp on Windows